# Mesos framework stays inactive due to "Authentication failed: EOF"

Tags: go, apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere, eremetic

I'm currently trying to deploy [Eremetic](https://www.github.com/eremetic-framework/eremetic) (version 0.28.0) on top of Marathon using the [configuration provided as an example](https://github.com/eremetic-framework/eremetic/blob/v0.28.0/misc/eremetic.json). I actually have been able to deploy it once, but suddenly, after trying to redeploy it, the framework stays inactive.

By inspecting the logs I noticed a constant attempt to connect to some service that apparently never succeeds because of some authentication problem.

```
2017/08/14 12:30:45 Connected to [REDACTED_MESOS_MASTER_ADDRESS]
2017/08/14 12:30:45 Authentication failed: EOF
```

It looks like the service returning an error is ZooKeeper and more precisely it looks like the error can be traced back to [this line](https://github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/blob/master/zk/conn.go#L433) in the Go ZooKeeper library. ZooKeeper however seems to work: I've tried to query it directly with `zkCli` and to run a small Spark job (where the Mesos master is given with `zk://` URL) and everything seems to work.

Unfortunately I'm not able to diagnose the problem further, what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a configuration problem. The master URL was simply wrong and this is how the error was reported.